# No logro leer un archivo json que se localiza en drive

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Necesito obtener la información de ese archivo *json* para poder darle forma a la página web que estoy construyendo pero no logro obtener esa información. no sé si lo estoy haciendo mal o que pero no me funciona de ninguna manera.

En este ejemplo trato de obtenerlo con *GET* pero no lo logro.

```js
var urlTxt = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1MvzV81How4b-wEdIzwscZtXyU_YIVyiP";

$.ajax(

url: urlTxt,
type: "GET",

success: function(mensaje) {

document.write(mensaje);

}



);
```

Comment: ¿Es un ejemplo esa es la url del archivo que quieres descargar? Por que ese enlace no conduce a la descarga de ningún archivo.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez es un ejemplo. Pero así mismo es la URL, caracteres.

Comment: Como dice Jaime, te faltan las llaves para pasar los parámetros a la llamada `ajax`. Por otro lado, ¿te da algún error en la consola?

Comment: necesitas un api key y limitarla a un dominio para que no genere gastos o exceder la quota

Comment: Prueba cambiando la url de google drive por esta: `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1MvzV81How4b-wEdIzwscZtXyU_YIVyiP` para obtener una descarga raw del archivo (cambia el id por alguno que funcione), y es probable que eso te redireccione a otra url, la cual quizas deberias capturar con `curl -L` en PHP por ejemplo. Visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834877/google-drive-raw-data)

Comment: Pero además de ser un ejemplo... ¿Necesitas el JSON como compartido en Google Drive o no? Es que si no es así, para buscarte uma URL de ejemplo... Has escogido una un poco especial, ¿no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que ese link te devolviera un archivo de texto, el código que tienes es correcto, solo le faltan las llaves. Te adjunto un ejemplo con un archivo real que sí funciona y puedes probar desde acá.

```js
var urlTxt = "https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791";
$.ajax(
    {
        url: urlTxt,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (mensaje) {
            document.write(mensaje);
        }
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: El problema es que el link jamás finaliza en .txt

Comment: @NuevoUsuario No es que el link no finalice en txt, es que el link que pones no devuelve NADA. Da igual si finaliza o no en `txt`, eso es irrelevante, lo que tiene que hacer es devolver un txt y el link que pones no devuelve nada. Le acabo de quitar el .txt y sigue funcionando exactamente igual

Comment: he editado la pregunta y he pasado la información a google drive que también hace lo mismo que la otra página, lleva directo a descarga.

Comment: En cuanto a permisos del archivo de Google Drive... ¿tienes permiso de lectura a acualquiera? Y otra cosa... veo que accedes directamente (no a través de API), así que estaría bien que añadieras `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown + ' / ' + textStatus) + console.log(jqXHR);
  }` como parámetro de la llamada `ajax` y nos digas qué error da. Me imagino que Unauthorized, pero ya nos contarás

Answer (score 0):

Json de ejemplo:

```
   {
        "fruit": "Apple",
        "size": "Large",
        "color": "Red"
    }
```

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/202761627/example_1.json',
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.fruit);
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta puede ser un buen código pero no responde a la cuestión propuesta, cuya dificultad en realidad es el acceso a la fuente del JSON, que es Google Drive

Comment: Ahi lo que haria falta es llegar a la url del json pero entiendo que drive lo va generando con hash aleatorios para que no se pueda acceder siempre directo al archivo